# Are formal characters like \[FormalA] to be used differently than other symbols?

Tags: programming, front-end, named-characters

I noticed that Mathematica has a set of special 'Formal' characters such as `\[FormalA]`, `\[FormalB]` , etc.. In the front end, it looks like a character with a dot above and below:

[image: formal characters]

It is not clear from the built-in [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/LettersAndLetterLikeForms.html#173509264) how these characters are to be used.

Would someone demonstrate?

Comment: Formal symbols are `Protected`, so they can't be assigned values (by default). So you can use it as a way of ensuring that your definitions don't have stray values. It has been used several times on this site (see some of the posts [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=formal+symbol) for examples), although I don't think a question has been asked explicitly about it.

Comment: Version 10 now has formal *Greek* letters, too.

Comment: @R.M. **Not all formal symbols are protected**: `\[FormalDelta]` is but `\[FormalPhi]` is not `Protected`. According to TechSupport, this is by design, as some formal symbols are used internally, some are not. This is aggrevating, as one cannot rely on that a formal symbol has no global value set by the user.

Comment: @R.M. Out of curiosity, would you know in which version of *Mathematica* `\[Formal]` characters were introduced?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Very often, especially new *Mathematica* users stumble over the following error: They gave, maybe hours ago, a symbol a value like `x=3`, and later they try to use it where a function really expects a symbol:

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

This leads of course to an error, because the `Minimize` call does not see the `x`, but only its value. The same happens when you try to derive this with `D` or `Dt` or `Integrate` expressions. Although the error message is very clear, most people get very confused and try to change their whole calculation.

Exactly for those situations, the formal parameter characters are made. They all share the attribute `Protected` which states that you cannot simply assign a value to them. Therefore, you can use them in situations where you maybe derive expressions or proof formulas or where you minimize an expression

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is a nice issue for the beginner's pitfalls question too

Answer (score 6):

I would like to point out that the shortcut to write out formal symbols is `:$a:`, where `:` is typed using `Esc`.  See the documentation [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/KeyboardShortcutListing.html.en).