# How to declare a function of variable?

Tags: functions

In my program, there are many functions relying on spatial coordinates: x, y, and z, which are also functions of time t, i.e., composite function. I need to differentiate some functions for example f:

```
    D[f[x[t], y[t], z[t]], t]
```

But because those coordinates appear so frequently, when I write x[t] instead of x my program becomes lengthy and lacks readability. So, how can I declare those coordinates as functions of time t at the start to tell *Mathematica* that the differentiation is relative to t, so I can use x, y , and z, afterwards as an abbreviation.

Comment: You can use `Dt` as in `Dt[f[x, y, z], t]`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried Dt[x^2, t], and Mma returns  2x*Dt[x, t]. whereas I need 2x*x'

Comment: The difference between Dt[x, t] and x' is : I can assign value to x', but I cannot assign value to 
Dt[x, t].

Comment: @user5463 No, you cannot assign a value to `x'`. It only seems you do it. Please read [this answer of mine](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15620/187) where I explain the details.

Comment: Thanks halirutan, I have a little problem with the result of differentiation when i'm using Runge–Kutta method. For example, D[x[t]^2, t] returns 2x[t]*x'[t], i have to replace x'[t] with dx by hand so that I can assign value to dx, is there a convenient way to handle it automatically?

Comment: Maybe `x@t` helps the readability. `D[f[x@t, y@t, z@t], t]` At least it avoids overloading brain with square brackets.

Comment: @user5463 Why dont you use a rule to replace each occurence of `x'[t]`? Something like `D[x[t]^2, t] /. x'[t] -> dx`.

Answer (score 3):

No one stops you from creating a variable holding your `Sequence` of `x[t]`, `y[t]` and `z[t]`! So an easy short cut is

```
vars = Sequence[x[t], y[t], z[t]];
D[f[vars], t]
```

When you need to access the single variables, you could go another way and use the *formal characters* which have some advantages as described [in this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19119/187)

```
x = \[FormalX][t];
y = \[FormalY][t];
z = \[FormalZ][t];
D[f[x, y, z], t]
```

Answer (score 3):

Your added comment suggest you want to replace the derivatives with symbols like `dx` etc. Maybe this does what you want:

```
ClearAll[x, y, z]

SetOptions[D, NonConstants -> {x, y, z}];

x /: D[x, t, NonConstants -> {x, y, z}] := dx;
y /: D[y, t, NonConstants -> {x, y, z}] := dy;
z /: D[z, t, NonConstants -> {x, y, z}] := dz;

D[f[x, y, z], t]
```

> `dz*Derivative[0, 0, 1][f][x, y, 
>      z] + dy*Derivative[0, 1, 0][f][
>      x, y, z] + 
>    dx*Derivative[1, 0, 0][f][x, y, z]`

To check that this does exactly what you said in the comments to your question:

```
D[x^2, t]
```

> `2 dx x`

Comment: Thanks Jens! That's what i want.