# Mathematica Empty Plot FourierSinSeries function

Tags: plotting, functions, evaluation, syntax

I'm trying to get a plot of different order Fourier series of the function x-1, why does Mathematica give me an empty plot?

```
f[x_, N_] := FourierSinSeries[x-1, x, N]
Plot[{f[x, 1], f[x, 5]}, {x, 0, 3}]
```

Executing f[x,1] and f[x,5] do give me valid functions. A workaround is:

```
f1=f[x,1]
f5=f[x,5]
Plot[{f1,f5},{x,0,3}]
```

Why does it only work that way?

Comment: Bad idea to use upper case `N` as a variable, since that symbol has a built-in meaning.

Answer (score 2):

That's because `Plot` is a *numerical* function which evaluates its first argument with *numerical* values of `x` while `FourierSinSeries` requires *symbolic* variable. What happens is that `Plot` internally makes an assignment like

```
 x = 0;
```

and then evaluates

```
 f[x, 1]
```

> ```
>  FourierSinSeries[-1, 0, 1]
> ```

The obtained expression isn't numeric, and `Plot` simply ignores it without warning.

Your workaround works because you preliminarily evaluate `FourierSinSeries` with unassigned `x` what results in an expression suitable for plotting:

```
 x =.;
 f[x, 1]
```

> (2 - 4/π) Sin[x]

---

This behavior (except the absence of a warning message) is documented under "Details and Options" on the Docs page for `Plot` :

> `Plot` has attribute `HoldAll` and evaluates `f` only after assigning
>   specific numerical values to `x`.

Comment: Another work around is to curry f.  Define `f[n_] := f[n] = Function[x, Evaluate@FourierSinSeries[x - 1, x, n]]`.  Then `Plot[{f[1][x], f[5][x]}, {x,0,3}]`.

Comment: @evanb Good demonstration of currying with memoization. But for safety it is better to use `\[FormalX]` instead of `x` in the definition for `f`.

Comment: Can you demonstrate?  I frankly never understood the use of the `Formal` parameters.  Maybe this deserves its own question?

Comment: @evanb In your function definition your `Evaluate` breaks the scope of `Function` and if `x` has a value, it will be substituted into the `FourierSinSeries[x - 1, x, n]` expression before evaluation of `FourierSinSeries`. The safety of formal parameters comes from the fact that they are `Protected` and you can't assign values to them. More lengthy explanation can be found in [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19119/280) answer.

Comment: I see.  It's to protect you from picking up state.  Thanks for the pointer / link!

Comment: I tried `x = 3;
f[n_] := f[n] = Function[x, Evaluate@FourierSinSeries[x - 1, x, n]]` (after quitting the kernel) and it works fine.  So in this case there doesn't seem to be any danger---`Evaluate` must understand that it is inside a `Function`.

Comment: @evanb The reason why it works in this case is not that `Evaluate` "understands" something: evaluating `f[n]` returns `Function[x, FourierSinSeries[2, 3, n]]` what demonstrates that the scope is indeed broken. What happend here is that the lexical replacement (which comes from the delayed definition `:=`) is performed inside of the body of `Function` *before* the `Evaluate` fires, i.e. when the scope is not broken yet. [continued in the next comment]

Comment: @evanb As a result `Function` renames its local variable `x` to `x$` what in effect protects it from being replaced by the value of `x` when `Evaluate` fires. This behavior is (a bit vaguely) [documented](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/VariablesInPureFunctionsAndRules.html): "In general, the Wolfram Language renames the formal parameters in an object like `Function[vars,body]` whenever `body` is modified in any way by the action of another pure function." In [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/124536/280) answer I give extended explanation of this behavior.

Comment: @evanb But your point is correct: in this case we won't get additional safety by using a formal symbol as a parameter because we already have subtle and *very limited* **additional** scoping due to the combination of `RuleDelayed` and `Function` (I forgot about this possibility when wrote the first comment). Such scoping isn't very reliable though (as I showed above).

Comment: Gotcha.  So here it's more of a best-practices thing, but in other examples it can really save you.

Comment: @evanb A detailed explanation of the variable renaming mechanics can be found in [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20776/280) answer (and after reading it I realized that my formulation above wasn't quite correct: actually it is namely `RuleDelayed` who renames `x` to `x$` inside of `Function`, because the latter is inert on that stage).

Comment: @evanb Yes, it is a best-practice rule: when you use `Evaluate` always remember that it can break scoping and hence you (possibly) have to introduce additional scoping/protection in order to avoid bugs.

Answer (score 0):

### Expressions don't get automatically evaluated inside the Plot function.

This is because `Plot` is `HoldAll`

### Workaround: use Evaluate

Including an `Evaluate` function:

```
f[x_, n_] := FourierSinSeries[x - 1, x, n];

Plot[{Evaluate@f[x, 1], Evaluate@f[x, 5]}, {x, 0, 3}]
```

Comment: That's on account of `Plot[]`'s `HoldAll` attribute.