# Capital Letters that are built-in symbols

Tags: core-language, built-in-symbols, faq

I'm trying to search for an answer to "What is the complete list of single capital letters that represent built-in *Mathematica* commands, symbols, or uses?"

For example:

> C, D, E, I, N, O

Is this the complete list? I'm teaching linear algebra in the fall, and I will warn students about using variable names that start with capital letters, but I'd also like to be specific about which particular letters will cause a problem.

Comment: Try running ``Select[Names["System`*"], StringLength[#] == 1 && UpperCaseQ[#] && ! StringMatchQ[ToString[FullForm[#]], "*Formal*"] &]``.

Comment: Just say no to *any* capital initials.

Comment: @J.M. Looks like an answer to me.

Comment: ``Cases[Names["System`*"], Alternatives @@ CharacterRange["A", "Z"]]``

Comment: @C. E., but not as it stands; I'll write something a bit longer later, unless you want to do so on my behalf. :)

Comment: @J.M. how did you format your comment in code format. I couldn't  do it with the context System` :(

Comment: @AHB it is there you can see it but it did not work becase we have one ` from the context System`

Comment: I have edited your comment, @Algohi; the trick is to enclose any snippet with a backtick within two sets of backticks.

Comment: @J.M. Aha, so I had previously three backticks. Got it. Thanks :)

Comment: However, note, that `K` is the only one among standard latin capitals that is not `Protected`. Also, some of the one-letter formal symbols are System` symbols, but not all: compare `Attributes@{\[FormalPhi], \[FormalCurlyPhi]}` (see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19108/are-formal-characters-like-formala-to-be-used-differently-than-other-symbols#comment274061_19108)).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To convert my comment into an answer: one can naively run `` Select[Names["System`*"], StringLength[#] == 1 &] `` to pick out built-in symbols that are only one character long. This will work in older versions of *Mathematica*, but ever since the introduction of [formal symbols](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/LettersAndLetterLikeForms.html#173509264) (which are, to be fair, in the `` System`​ `` context and are one-character expressions as well), this needs to be finessed further. Thus, we must add extra criteria to filter out the classical list of reserved capital letters (as of the current version):

```
Select[Names["System`*"], StringLength[#] == 1 &&
                          UpperCaseQ[#] &&
                          StringFreeQ[CharacterName[#], "Formal"] &]
   {"C", "D", "E", "I", "K", "N", "O"}
```

A (more expensive) alternative uses the new entity framework through `WolframLanguageData[]` like so:

```
Select[WolframLanguageData[], StringLength[CanonicalName[#]] == 1 &] // CanonicalName
   {"N", "C", "I", "O", "D", "E"}
```

but this misses `K`, which is the arbitrary index used for explicit sums and products returned as solutions by symbolic functions (akin to the use of `C` as an arbitrary constant). (Try e.g. `RSolve[x[k + 1] == x[k] Prime[k], x, k]`.)

Answer (score 12):

They are:

> C D E I K N O

It's easy to know.
Just open a notebook and type the capital alphabet.
Those changing color to black are protected.

[image: ans]

Comment: It's also easy to remember: ONE D--- Never mind.

Comment: @Peltio, don't you start. :P

Comment: @AHB What does "type the capital alphabet" mean? I can't get this to work.

Comment: He's telling you to type each capital letter manually in each cell, @David.

Comment: @J.M Aha! I get it. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: @Peltio I'm so pure boy.When I realize this,your this comment come to my mind. :)

Comment: @Peltio Although years have passed, I cannot still get your first comment. What did you mean?

Comment: @AHB this will take some creativity on your end, how to arrange the letters.

Comment: The code below takes 130 seconds on my computer to generate all possible Mnemonics that represent words. Be warned that Peltio's  saucy word choice that he could not write hear appears in the list.

Comment: `(
Permutations[{"E","N","I","O","K","C","D"}]
//Map[StringJoin]
//Map[
 Select[SpellingCorrectionList@#,
  x|->ContainsExactly[
       DeleteCases[" "]@Characters@x,
       Characters@#
       ]
  ]&
 ]
//DeleteDuplicates
)`

Comment: Among the candidates, removing the not safe for stack exchange saucy ones, the most reasonable candidates are "INK CODE" "INK DECO"  "ION DECK"  and  "COED INK"

Answer (score 8):

With a fresh kernel, use

```
Select[CharacterRange["A", "Z"], NameQ]
```

> {"C", "D", "E", "I", "K", "N", "O"}

Answer (score 7):

```
Quiet[Select[CharacterRange["A", "Z"], Context[#] == "System`" &]]
```

> ```
> {C, D, E, I, K, N, O}
> ```

Hope this can help.

Comment: This did not work for me. I entered `Select[CharacterRange["A", "Z"], UnsameQ[Context[#], $Context] &]` and got things like: `Context::notfound: Symbol A not found. >>` and `General::stop: Further output of Context::notfound will be suppressed during this calculation. >>` even though I first quit the kernel.

Comment: In Mathematica 10.4 I needed to add `ToExpression` thus `Select[ToExpression /@ CharacterRange["A", "Z"], 
 UnsameQ[Context[#], $Context] &]`

Comment: Sorry @David ,maybe I miss something yesterday.And I have a verification just now.

Comment: @yode No need to be sorry. That worked. I totally appreciate your help.