# variable K cannot be deleted

Tags: system-variables

If a value is assigned to a variable that is named by capital K it cannot be deleted. This effect can be observed directly after start of the program.

Is this a bug?

[image]

Comment: This is why new users should **avoid** using variable names that start with capital letters. In this case, `K` is a **built-in** symbol used by internal functions as a dummy variable for integrals/products/sums, e.g. `DSolve[{y'[x] == Sin[Sin[x]]}, y, x]`. Of course, you can't delete it!

Comment: Additionally: please do not use the [tag:bugs] tag in the future for new questions, until other people have confirmed that what you have encountered is a bug.

Comment: This is the first programming language I know where capital letters at the beginning are forbidden, so it is a bug.

Comment: @granularbastard Capital letters at the beginning of variables aren't forbidden, they're just a bad idea because you might try to use a built-in symbol (which are all capitalized).

Comment: The help gives no hint about a reserved meaning of "K". Also there is no hint for "built-in symbol"

Comment: That it is not listed in the help file is certainly a fault of *Mathematica* (which you should certainly [write to support](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=Feedback) for), but there is at least some information when you evaluate `?K`.

Comment: You would think it would pop up as protected, but maybe `K` is left unprotected as a result of its use as a dummy variable? I think this is an easy to avoid mistake, however, and the OP shows that there is some level of advisory that pops up when you check the description.

Comment: [A related thread.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/117877)

Comment: A hint is that it's black, not blue. @CATrevillian `C` is used as a dummy variable and it is `Protected`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Wolfram Language currently uses seven single letter capital letters for various core system functions: `C`, `D`, `E`, `I`, `K`, `N`, and `O`. Mnemonically: `OINCKED`

The other 19 capital letters are available to use, at least in current versions:

```
data = {#, Symbol[#], ToExpression[# <> "::usage"]} & /@ CharacterRange["A", "Z"];
Grid[data, Alignment -> Left, Frame -> All, BaseStyle -> "Text"]
```

[image]

Of these seven symbols, `K` is the only undocumented symbol (in the sense that it does not have a reference page). I would consider that a bug or shortcoming in the documentation.

Comment: Also `CODE INK` - two small meaningful words. Or maybe `KODE INC` an imaginary company.

Comment: Peltio was about to give a... saucy mnemonic [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/117877/capital-letters-that-are-built-in-symbols?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment318452_117879), but thankfully he restrained himself. :)

Answer (score 5):

`K` is part of the `` System` `` context. You were removing symbols from the `` Global` `` context only, so `K` wasn't affected. It could be unset with `K=.`.

That said, when doing interactive work, avoid using any symbols whose name starts with a capital letter, as these may conflict with System symbols or package symbols.

Do not set any value for `K` and do not attempt to `Remove` it as this will break things. `K` is used as the summation index when a generic `Sum` is returned. An example from the documentation of `RSolve`:

```
RSolve[a[n + 1] == a[n] + f[n], a[n], n]

(* {{a[n] -> C[1] + Sum[f[K[1]], {K[1], 0, -1 + n}]}} *)
```

---

I do not know why `K` is not `Protected`. It seems like it would make sense to protect it as people regularly assign to it by accident.

Answer (score 2):

If K is evaluated  then click on "description of K" and you get information:

> K is a default generic name for a summation index in a symbolic sum.

The bug is that this information is missing in the help.

Comment: To clear `K` of an assigned value, use `K =.`