# Indexed array cannot be named by the name of its elements

Tags: indexed-variable, indexing

Indexed Arrays or lists can be created by

```
Array[k,3]
(*{k[1], k[2], k[3]}*)
```

However I would like to name this list also by `k`, i.e.

```
k=Array[k,3]
```

that leads to a recursion error. My fantasy is that if I use `k` then I would mean the whole list and a single element I would access by `k[i]`. This corresponds to common writing style in mathematical publications (see photo below). Using capital letters

```
K=Array[k,3]
```

is not recommended as e.g. `K` is a [reserved name](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/213524/69288). I could of course call the list by some other name but then one looses overview in symbolic computing as one has 2 names for the same object. How should I name in MMA indexed objects to keep track of my variables?

---

Example from a mathematical paper where we the same letter $T$ is used to refer to the object in general and indexed $T_{i_1,\ldots,i_d}$ to refer to single elements.

[image]

Reference of picture:

Elina Robeva: Orthogonal decomposition of symmetric tensors, SIAM J. Matrix Anal. Appl. 37, p.86, 2016

Comment: One possibility is `SetAttributes[Subscript, HoldFirst]; k = {Subscript[k, 1], Subscript[k, 2], Subscript[k, 3]}`

Comment: I simply add an "s" to the name of the elements.

Comment: I'd use an `s` for the name of the list (`ks = Array[k,3]`) which is maybe what you meant?

Comment: I know that you probably think the rationale here is obvious, but I think it would be helpful to us, but more importantly for yourself, to clearly articulate why you want this. There are many, many workarounds possible here, but rather than throw darts in the dark, it would be better if you clarified your representational and semantic needs. What are the specific scenarios/computations where you think this will help you?

Comment: @lericr The motivation is obvious to name things in such a way. I added an example from literature.

Comment: Okay, then maybe you want to use TeX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure this is appropriate as an answer, but the comments didn't get us anywhere.

You said,

> My fantasy is that if I use k then I would mean the whole list and a single element I would access by k[i].

Well, your fantasy is fulfilled, with the small caveat that the more idiomatic notation would be `k[[i]]` instead of `k[i]`. We could, for example have `k = Range[3]`, and you can't really get much closer to what you're asking for. The symbol `k` evaluates to the whole list (i.e. `k` "means" the whole list), and single elements are accessed by `k[[i]]`.

The pretty formula you posted in your update uses this exact same semantic, just a different notation: subscript translates to Part.

And your first example,

```
Array[k,3]
(*{k[1], k[2], k[3]}*)
```

is very close semantically to this same idea, it just re-appropriates function application to mean indexed element. You said,

> I would like to name this list also by k

but that is exactly what you've done. Or at least, that's an acceptable interpretation of what you've done. You have the concept of some array `k`, and you refer to "elements" as `k[i]`.

Unless you weren't previously familiar with Part, this is almost surely not what you're asking for. And yet, it matches perfectly what you *said*. This is why I suggested that you reflect on your actual need.

Let's look more closely at what you said:

> I would like to name this list also by k, i.e. k=Array[k,3]

This is where things get confused. You *said* that you wanted to "name the list", but what you wrote was actually setting a value for the symbol `k`. That's not assigning an inherent name to the list. The list is anonymous. All expressions are anonymous. This is instead assigning a value to k. You can have as many such assignments as you want:

```
a = b = c = d = Array[k, 3]
```

There's no reason to expect some automatic definition along the lines of

```
NameOf[{k[1], k[2], k[3]}]
```

that evaluates to "k". If Alice were cloned, would the name of the clone necessarily be Alice?

You introduced a subtlety in the form of a naming error. You showed us this list: `{k[1], k[2], k[3]}`. Then you said that you wanted to access elements of the list by `k[i]`. But you can't *access* the list with `k[i]` because the elements of the list actually *are* of the form `k[i]`. Analogously, in the pretty formula you posted an element `T_i` would be some value, it wouldn't be the formal variable `T_i`. It is thus perfectly clear why `k=Array[k,3]` leads to infinite recursion, but you somehow want to just gloss over that.

Or put another way, you are expecting, on the one hand, for k to *evaluate* to {k[1], k[2], k[3]} but simultaneously be a formal, pure, static symbol.

So, I say again, you need to very clearly decide what semantic you are trying to capture. If it's accessing elements of a structure, you have Part, and function application, and even Indexed. If you want something purely presentational, with formal variables as aliases, then you have Subscript, Indexed, Part might still be made to work, judicious use of HoldForm could work, or maybe a clever use of Format. To take one of those, you could try

```
k = Array[HoldForm@*k, 3]
```

but I think that'll probably blow up on you at some point.