# How do I expand an exponential function?

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions

First of all, apologies for the formatting, I can't seem to enter it as code here?
My question is as follows:

I have \Theta defined as follows:

```
\[Theta] = ArcCos[
\!\(\*UnderscriptBox[
StyleBox["1", "Input"], \(2\)]\)[Cos[
\!\(\*UnderscriptBox[\(2*\[Pi]*kx\), 
SqrtBox[\(N\)]]\)] + Cos[
\!\(\*UnderscriptBox[\(2*\[Pi]*ky\), 
SqrtBox[\(N\)]]\)]]]
```

I would now like to evaluate `e^[iTheta]`, where it fully expands this function using the above defined theta. However, when I use Expand[e^[iTheta]], for example, it just prints out `e^[iTheta]`. How can I do this?

Comment: `e^[iTheta]` has multiple things wrong with it: 1) `e` is a symbol, I assume you want `E` for Euler's constant. 2) The square brackets (see docs for `Construct`) are for function calls, associations etc. you want parentheses `(...)` instead. 3) `iTheta` should be `i \[Theta]` as a space is needed to multiply them, and finally 4) it's uppercase `I` for the imaginary unit, not `i` the symbol. Putting it all together: `E^(I \[Theta])` or even this: `Exp[I \[Theta]]` which calls the `Exp` function.

Comment: Also, don't use `N` as it's a builtin, use `n` instead. You're doing some things with Underscripts and I think you're trying to do fractions. This won't work. I've reformatted your code like this, but can you confirm it's correct? `\[Theta] = ArcCos[
  1/2 (Cos[(2*\[Pi]*kx)/Sqrt[n]] + Cos[(2*\[Pi]*ky)/Sqrt[n]])]`

Comment: For me, `e^[iTheta]` yields an error, `Syntax::sntxf: "e^" cannot be followed by "[iTheta]".`

Comment: @flinty Thanks for your comment. Sorry, I am still new to Mathematica, so what does it mean that ```N```is a builtin? The N I used is a constant, whereas the kx and ky are variables, does that have something to do with it?

Comment: @Q.Ask Mathematica has some single letter capital letters that mean special things and should be avoided as names of your own symbols - use lowercase instead. `N` is a function used like `N[expr]` that gives the numerical value of an expression. Also avoid using these ones for your custom symbols too `C`, `K`, `O`, `I`, `E`, `D`. You can select and right click on a symbol and get help to see if it has a special meaning ('K' doesn't have a help page). You can read more [here in this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/221098/72682)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is meant to be

```
Exp[ I ArcCos[
 1/2 Cos[(2 \[Pi] I k)/Sqrt[N] ] +  1/2 Cos[(2 \[Pi] I ky)/Sqrt[N] ] ]] // 
TrigToExp // FullSimplify
```

it yields

```
1/2 (Cosh[(2 k \[Pi])/Sqrt[N]] + Cosh[(2 y\[Pi])/Sqrt[N]]  + 
2 I Sqrt[1-1/4 (Cosh[(2 k \[Pi])/Sqrt[N]] 
+ Cosh[(2 ky \[Pi])/Sqrt[N]])^2])
```