# How to generate alphabetical parameters in differential solution results

Tags: differential-equations

I want to generate alphabetical parameters in the differential solution as shown in the figure below:
$$\left(\frac{\mathrm d^2}{\mathrm d r^2}+\frac1{r}\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d r}\right)\left(\frac{\mathrm d^2\phi}{\mathrm d r^2}+\frac1{r}\frac{\mathrm d\phi}{\mathrm d r}\right)=0$$

$$\phi=A\ln r+B r^2\ln r+C r^2+D$$
But I get a lot of error warnings when I do this:

```
L = (D[#, {r, 2}] + 1/r D[#, r]) &;
f[i_] := FromCharacterCode[i + 64]
DSolve[L[(D[φ[r], {r, 2}] + 1/r D[φ[r], r])] == 
  0, φ[r], r, GeneratedParameters -> f]
```

What can I do to solve this problem better?

Comment: Note that `C`, `D`, `E`, `I`, etc. are ``System` `` symbols, usually with built-in definitions that will cause trouble later.  [Best to avoid capitals.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/4999)  Perhaps formal capitals?: `DSolve[y''[x] == 3 y[x] y'[x] + (3 y[x]^2 + 4 y[x] + 1), y[x], x] /. 
 C[i_] :> FromCharacterCode[
   i + 1 + ToCharacterCode["\[FormalCapitalA]"]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two issues

1. Define `f` for [`Integer`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integer.html).
2. Return a [`Symbol`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Symbol.html).

Technically you can return the string as you are now but you will run into issues down the line.

```
ClearAll[f]
L = (D[#, {r, 2}] + 1/r D[#, r]) &;
f[i_Integer] := Symbol@FromCharacterCode[i + 64]
```

Then

```
DSolve[L[(D[φ[r], {r, 2}] + 1/r D[φ[r], r])] == 0, φ[r], r, GeneratedParameters -> f]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

without errors.

Hope this helps.

PS: You may also run into issues with symbols like [`C`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/C.html) and [`I`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/I.html).  This is why it is not recommended to define symbols (outside of packages) that start with capital letters. See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/117877).

Comment: Thank you very much. In addition, how to generate independent parameters like those in the picture of this problem (for example, only one parameter `C`)?

Comment: Try `ClearAll[f]; f[i_Integer] := Subscript[\[DoubleStruckF], i]`. See the [Special Characters](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SpecialCharacters.html) guide.

Answer (score 5):

Why not replacing afterwards?:

```
i = 65;
DSolve[L[(D[φ[r], {r, 2}] + 1/r D[φ[r], r])] == 0, φ[r], r] /. 
  C[_] :> FromCharacterCode[i++]
```

[image]

Comment: This approach does not work on `DSolve[y''[x] == 3 y[x] y'[x] + (3 y[x]^2 + 4 y[x] + 1), y[x], x]`. Better to use `DSolve[y''[x] == 3 y[x] y'[x] + (3 y[x]^2 + 4 y[x] + 1), y[x], x] /. C[i_] :> FromCharacterCode[i + 64]`, though it's better to avoid capitals.