# Why, if you write the expression in the form of two functions, does the code stop working?

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics, mathematical-optimization, parallelization

I would like to find the minimum of the function EER[a, v] using parallel computing.

If I write the code like this, it works:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

Kx[a_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[(E^(-((2 r)/a)) (-2 a + r))/(
    a^2 r NIntegrate[Exp[-(r/a)]^2 r^2, {r, 0, \[Infinity]}])*
    r^2, {r, 0, \[Infinity]}];

Ko[v_?NumericQ] := ((-1.05 + 0.69* v)* v)/(2.27 + v *(-3.02 + 1.1* v));

EER[a_, v_] := Ko[v]*Kx[a];

Exx = 
 ParallelTable[{v, 
   FindMinimum[{Etmp = EER[a, v], (0.1 < a < 30)}, {{a, 1}}, 
    EvaluationMonitor :> {Pause[0.1], 
      Print[" Current a=", a, " E=", Etmp]}]}, {v, {7.5, 10, 12.5, 
    15}}]
```

Now I want to denote part of the expression in Kx[a_?NumericQ] like K[a_?NumericQ] but in the case of such entry, the code stops working. Why doesn't the code work?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

K[a_?NumericQ] := (E^(-((2 r)/a)) (-2 a + r))/(
 a^2 r NIntegrate[Exp[-(r/a)]^2 r^2, {r, 0, \[Infinity]}])

Kx[a_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[K[a]*r^2, {r, 0, \[Infinity]}];

Ko[v_?NumericQ] := ((-1.05 + 0.69* v)* v)/(2.27 + v *(-3.02 + 1.1* v));

EER[a_, v_] := Ko[v]*Kx[a];

Exx = 
 ParallelTable[{v, 
   FindMinimum[{Etmp = EER[a, v], (0.1 < a < 30)}, {{a, 1}}, 
    EvaluationMonitor :> {Pause[0.1], 
      Print[" Current a=", a, " E=", Etmp]}]}, {v, {7.5, 10, 12.5, 
    15}}]
```

Comment: Short answer: Do not use `K`, rename to `K2` for example. Longer answer: `K` is a built-in symbol, in particular `Context[K]` is ``System` ``. This means that the definition you have given for `K` is not automatically distributed to other kernels, only definitions for symbols in ``Global` `` are.

Comment: @user293787, thank you very much!

Comment: use small k, always in Mathematica avoid using capitals, because they are mostly reserved for predefined functions

Comment: The list of capital letters that are built in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/117877/86543

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Your functions can be evaluated symbolically

```
Kx[a_] = Integrate[(E^(-((2 r)/a)) (-2 a + r))/
    (a^2 r Integrate[Exp[-(r/a)]^2 r^2, {r, 0, ∞}])*
   r^2, {r, 0, ∞}]
```

[image]

```
Ko[v_] =
 ((-1.05 + 0.69*v)*v)/(2.27 + v*(-3.02 + 1.1*v)) //
   Rationalize // FullSimplify
```

[image]

```
EER[a_, v_] = Ko[v]*Kx[a]
```

[image]

```
min[v_] = MinValue[{EER[a, v] // Normal,
   1/10 <= a <= 30}, a]
```

[image]

```
arg[v_] := ArgMin[{EER[a, v] // Normal,
   1/10 <= a <= 30}, a]

Off[ArgMin::wksol]

Show[
 Plot3D[EER[a, v], {v, 15/2, 15}, {a, 1/10, 1},
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {v, a, EER}),
  ClippingStyle -> None,
  PlotRange -> All],
 Graphics3D[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Point[{#, arg[#], min[#]} & /@
     Range[15/2, 15, 1/2]]}]]
```

[image]

```
Prepend[
  N@{#, arg[#], min[#]} & /@ Range[15/2, 15, 1/2],
  {v, a, "E"}] // Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]